# Nativescript java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError on Android in Release only

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I have a NativeScript app which runs fine if i build it in debug mode. 
On the same device in release mode, the app crashes on startup and in logs i see the following:

```
01-15 16:23:01.474 12229 12229 E script.demo: No implementation found for void com.tns.AndroidJsV8Inspector.init() (tried Java_com_tns_AndroidJsV8Inspector_init and Java_com_tns_AndroidJsV8Inspector_init__)
01-15 16:23:01.474 12229 12229 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-15 16:23:01.475 12229 12229 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 16:23:01.475 12229 12229 E AndroidRuntime: Process: org.nativescript.demo, PID: 12229
01-15 16:23:01.475 12229 12229 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.tns.AndroidJsV8Inspector.init() (tried Java_com_tns_AndroidJsV8Inspector_init and Java_com_tns_AndroidJsV8Inspector_init__)
```

Also the size of the release apk is smaller (38MB) then the debug version (46MB). I thought this might have something to do with minifying/shrinking etc. and that this causes the problem.
so i added this to my gradle:

```
android {  
 lintOptions {
  checkReleaseBuilds false
}
defaultConfig {  
  applicationId "org.nativescript.demo"
  multiDexEnabled true
  generatedDensities = []
}  
aaptOptions {  
  additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
}  
 buildTypes {
   release {
      minifyEnabled false //keeps unused methods instead of removing them
      shrinkResources false
  }
}
```

this also does not help...
I'm out of ideas

Thanks for any hint

**Update**
package.json:

```
    {
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.demo",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.1.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.1.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.4",
    "@types/text-encoding": "0.0.35",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.1.0",
    "nativescript-bluetooth": "1.3.1",
    "nativescript-feedback": "1.3.3",
    "nativescript-floatingactionbutton": "5.0.0",
    "nativescript-hook-debug-production": "1.0.4",
    "nativescript-localize": "4.1.0",
    "nativescript-modal-datetimepicker": "1.1.12",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "7.6.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-chart": "3.11.1",
    "nativescript-ui-dataform": "3.10.0",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~5.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.0",
    "text-encoding": "0.7.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.1.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.19.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~7.1.4"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "author": "Demo"
}
```

Comment: The app started crashing even before you modified the gradle file Or it's result of modifying the gradle file?

Comment: @Manoj it crashed also before. this is just what i tried

Comment: That's strange, I hope you are using the latest GA version of `tns-android`. The result is same even when you create a fresh hello world template?

Comment: i attached my package.json to my question. i use 5.1.0 of tns-android.
No, the hello world app works fine in debug and release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of Trial and Error i found it. 
It is the package

```
"nativescript-hook-debug-production": "1.0.4"
```

which caused the issue.

After removing it, it worked.